# Edittext Focus and click

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have Two `EditText`s. I want On First `EditText`s click clear the second and on second edittext click clear the first one. So I have tried `OnClickListener` and `OnTouchListener`. But it is not working properly.

```
 et_email.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!(et_email.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && et_mobile.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                        et_mobile.setText("");
                        et_mobile.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        et_mobile.setFocusable(true);
                        et_mobile.requestFocus();
                    }
                    return true; // return is important...
                } else
                    return false;
            }
        });
        et_mobile.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!(et_email.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && et_mobile.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                        et_email.setText("");
                        et_mobile.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        et_mobile.setFocusable(true);
                        et_mobile.requestFocus();
                    }
                    return true; // return is important...
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

But the problem is Focus is not setting on first touch and while clicking and unable to clear `EditText`.

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not working properly.`?

Comment: Use code formats for Native methods and variable. It helps in understanding the problem a lot.

Comment: instead on ontouch use onclick listner

Answer (score 1):

First add this to your Edittext layouts:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Without this line, the `EditText` will react to touch-mode, and only listen to your **onClick()** the second time you click your `EditText` bar.
This will disable touch-mode for `EditText`, and fire **onClick()** in first time

> [focusableInTouchMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusableInTouchMode)
>
> **Note:** boolean that controls whether a view can take focus while in touch mode. If this is true for a view, that view can gain focus when clicked on, and can keep focus if another view is clicked on that doesn't have this attribute set to true.

than do as follows:
**EditText1**

```
EditText et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText1);
et_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do this
        et_mobile.setText("");

        //or this
        et_mobile.getText().clear();         
    }
});
```

**EditText2**

```
EditText et_mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText2);
et_mobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do this
        et_email.setText("");

        //or this
        et_email.getText().clear();         
    }
});
```

This should help u out.

Answer (score 0):

you are clearing the first one one touching the  first one, change your variable names in first listener like this

```
if (!(et_email.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && et_mobile.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
        et_mobile.setText("");
        et_email.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        et_email.setFocusable(true);
        et_email.requestFocus();
    }
    return true; // return is important...
} else
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you (it works for me)

```
    edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);



    edit1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            edit2.setText("");
        }
    });

    edit2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            edit1.setText("");
        }
    });
```